# "Targeted" Brute-Force an Local App password

Tags: brute-force

I can't remember my password for a locally installed app but I wrote it down poorly and am sure of 6 letters/numbers out of 11.

I generated a list of all the possibilities given that the badly written letters could only be 2 or 3 possibilities per character.

It gave me a list of 216 combinations that I would like to run through the app on my mac.

I browsed and all I could find are some shady software that would do dictionary attacks... Is it possible to do a "targeted" brute-force attack using only tools available in the OS?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you have a password hash or a prompt you have to enter the password into? What do you mean by "without 3rd party software"?

Comment: @AndrolGenhald 1) I have a prompt for the password  
2) by 3rd party I mean by maybe using Terminal or some other tool available within the operating system.

Comment: Is Python installed on the machine?

Comment: @Nomad It is not, but if executing what is mentioned above is impossible without installing anything, I can download Python.

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 quick options I can come up with from the top of my head, which are `/usr/bin/expect` (if this is available on mac), or Python's Pexpect library.

I don't know how `expect` does file IO, but for Python/Pexpect this obviously isn't a problem and you should be able to do what you're trying in 10-15 lines of code.

Comment: Alright, I guess I have to deepen my coding abilities!
Thank you!